# Parse background job add multiple record stops after 21 records

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to add multiple records via Parse background job. I am not getting any error it's just stop saving records after 21 records. Here's my code:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

Parse.Cloud.job('usagovJobsRunner', function (request, status) {
  var promises = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
    promises.push(Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: 'http://jobs.github.com/positions.json',
      followRedirects: true,
      params: {
        page: index
      }
    }));
  }

  var jobs = [];
  Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function () {

    console.log('arguments length: ' + arguments.length);

    _.each(arguments, function (page) {
      console.log('page lenght: ' + page.data.length);

      _.each(page.data, function (job) {
        var model = new (Parse.Object.extend('Jobs'));
        model.set({
          jobId: job.id,
          title: job.title,
          description: job.description,
          location: job.location,
          jobPosting: new Date(job.created_at),
          type: job.type,
          company: job.company,
          companyUrl: job.company_url,
          companyLogoUrl: job.company_logo,
          source: 'Github Jobs',
          jobUrl: job.url
        });
        jobs.push(model)
      });
    });

    console.log('jobs count: ' + jobs.length);

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    // save all the newly created objects
    Parse.Object.saveAll(jobs, {
      success: function (objs) {
        // objects have been saved...
        console.log('jobs saved.');
        status.success('Github Jobs runner successfully loaded ' + objs.length + ' jobs');
      },
      error: function (error) { 
        // an error occurred...
        console.log(error);
        status.error('Error: ' + error);
      }
    });


    status.success();
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    status.error(err);
  });

});
```

Here are my logs:

> I2015-08-28T10:50:31.327Z]arguments length: 2
>   I2015-08-28T10:50:31.328Z]page lenght: 50
>   I2015-08-28T10:50:31.363Z]page lenght: 50
>   I2015-08-28T10:50:31.404Z]jobs count: 100
>   I2015-08-28T10:50:31.442Z]v15: Ran job usagovJobsRunner with:   Input:
>   {}   Result: undefined

Comment: Don't mix promises with traditional callbacks, choose one style and stick with it. Call `status.success();` only once when everything is complete.

Comment: @Wain removing last status.success(); worked. I have another question that I don't know the max number page count of githhub do you have any suggestion for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix promises with traditional callbacks, choose one style and stick with it. Call `status.success();` only once when everything is complete.

For calling to an arbitrary page depth you should create a plain JS function which takes a page number and returns a promise which is completed with the page data and page number. Now, you can call that function and when it's complete you can check if another page needs to be loaded and you also know what the page number is. When you get to the end you can call `status.success()`